# Why doesn't my polymorphic_type field get assigned automatically by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance

I'm using single table inheritance in conjunction with a polymorphic association.  Here are my models.

```
class ChangeInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eventable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :track_condition_changes, :as => :eventable, :class_name => "ChangeInformation"
  #other associations omitted
end

class TrackConditionChange < ChangeInformation

end
```

The change_informations table has the following fields:

```
type               #sti field
change_code
eventalbe_id       #polymorphic id
eventable_type     #polymorphic type
description
```

When I use the following create method:

```
TrackConditionChange.create(:change_code => 1, :eventable_id => 3 :description => "test")
```

a TrackConditionChange record is created, with the type field populated, however, the eventable_type field (which should be Race) is not populated. I was under the impression that rails populated this field automatically similar to the STI type field.  Was I under the wrong impression or is there a problem with my associaition setup.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only passing in the eventable_id, how will it know what type it is? You will have to either pass the entire eventable object or build it based on the track_condition_changes relationship:

**1. Pass the eventable object:**

```
race = Race.find(3)
TrackConditionChange.create(:change_code => 1, :eventable => race, :description => "test")
```

**2. Build and save based on the relationship:**

```
race = Race.find(3)
race.track_condition_changes << TrackConditionChange.new(:change_code => 1, :description => "test")
```

Comment: Beerlington - thanks for the help.  Somehow I convinced myself that rails could figure out the type from the associations, but upon further reflection I see what the problem was.  Thanks again!